# Setting Property Causes EXC_BAD_ACCESS crash (CLLocationManager Singleton)

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, singleton, key-value-observing

I been banging my head at this for the past few days and it beginning to slowly drain me. I am trying to make CLLocationManager Singleton as I need a location for two other components of my app. However, I keep getting EXC_BAD_ACCESS when I go set the currentLocation property. When I do get past it, I get a SIGABRT on main.m Oh and to top it all off, when does get past, along with the SIGABRT I am informed that my KVO message was received but not handled and I have no idea what that means.

Any help is appreciated along with resources on KVO and/or resources to basics I should know before using KVO

LocationFetch.h

```
@interface LocationFetch : NSObject <CLLocationManagerDelegate>

+(LocationFetch *) sharedInstance;

@property (nonatomic,strong) CLLocationManager *locationManager;
@property (nonatomic, strong) CLLocation *currentLocation;

-(void)startingUpdatingLocation;
-(void)stopUpdatingLocation;

@end
```

LocationFetch.m

```
#import "LocationFetch.h"

@implementation LocationFetch

@synthesize locationManager, currentLocation;

+(LocationFetch *) sharedInstance
{
    static LocationFetch *instance;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        instance = [[self alloc]init];
        });
    return instance;
}
- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if(self)
    {

        self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc]init];
        self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
        self.locationManager.distanceFilter = 100;
        self.locationManager.delegate = self;
        //Request Authorization
        if ([self.locationManager respondsToSelector:@selector(requestWhenInUseAuthorization)])
        {
            [self.locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
        }
    }
    return self;
}
- (void)startingUpdatingLocation
{
    [self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
    NSLog(@"Starting Location Updates");
}
-(void)stopUpdatingLocation
{
    [self.locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];
     NSLog(@"Stopping Location Updates");
}
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"Location updates failed with %@", error);
}
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray<CLLocation *> *)locations
{
    CLLocation *location = [locations lastObject];
    NSLog(@"LocationFetch sharedInstance: Latitude %+.6f, Longitude %+.6f\n",
          location.coordinate.latitude,
          location.coordinate.longitude);
    self.currentLocation = location;
}



@end
```

part of WeatherFetch.m (this is where the observer is being registered)

```
-(id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if(self)
    {
        [[LocationFetch sharedInstance] addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"currentLocation" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:nil];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object  

change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context
{
    if([keyPath isEqualToString:@"currentLocation"]) {
        [self setWeatherLocation];
        [self sendWeatherRequest];
        NSLog(@"Observer has received message");
        [self removeObserver:self forKeyPath:@"currentLocation" context:nil];
    }
}
```

EDIT: This was the guide I was following for the Singleton : http://derpturkey.com/cllocationmanager-singleton/

Another EDIT: Okay I got past the EXC_BAD_ACCESS error by removing the property attributes of strong and nonatomic for CLLocationManager and CLLocation but now the SIGABRT is now a more critical issue, here is the debug output from the exception. On the bright side, KVO appears to be notifitied now, just dont understand the error "message was received but not handled"

```
2016-06-24 21:25:51.111 TrafficAlarmClock[1504:18554] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '(
    "<CALayer: 0x7f95a043eb00>"
): An -observeValueForKeyPath:ofObject:change:context: message was received but not handled.
Key path: currentLocation
Observed object: <LocationFetch: 0x7f95a040c5a0>
Change: {
    kind = 1;
    new = "<+40.75921100,-73.98463800> +/- 5.00m (speed -1.00 mps / course -1.00) @ 6/24/16, 9:25:50 PM Eastern Daylight Time";
}
Context: 0x1050f7c08'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000105f97d85 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0000000105682deb objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000105f97cbd +[NSException raise:format:] + 205
    3   Foundation                          0x00000001052e71ae -[NSObject(NSKeyValueObserving) observeValueForKeyPath:ofObject:change:context:] + 168
    4   Foundation                          0x0000000105213cad NSKeyValueNotifyObserver + 347
    5   Foundation                          0x0000000105212f39 NSKeyValueDidChange + 466
    6   Foundation                          0x00000001052e7fff -[NSObject(NSKeyValueObservingPrivate) _changeValueForKeys:count:maybeOldValuesDict:usingBlock:] + 912
    7   Foundation                          0x0000000105210804 -[NSObject(NSKeyValueObservingPrivate) _changeValueForKey:key:key:usingBlock:] + 60
    8   Foundation                          0x000000010526ea9b _NSSetObjectValueAndNotify + 261
    9   TrafficAlarmClock                   0x00000001050f2143 -[LocationFetch locationManager:didUpdateLocations:] + 227
    10  CoreLocation                        0x0000000105192418 CLClientGetCapabilities + 20974
    11  CoreLocation                        0x000000010518e823 CLClientGetCapabilities + 5625
    12  CoreLocation                        0x00000001051892dd CLClientInvalidate + 923
    13  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000105ebd2ec __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 12
    14  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000105eb2f75 __CFRunLoopDoBlocks + 341
    15  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000105eb2d28 __CFRunLoopRun + 2472
    16  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000105eb20f8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 488
    17  GraphicsServices                    0x0000000108660ad2 GSEventRunModal + 161
    18  UIKit                               0x000000010634ef09 UIApplicationMain + 171
    19  TrafficAlarmClock                   0x00000001050f1b6f main + 111
    20  libdyld.dylib                       0x0000000108fd192d start + 1
    21  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Another EDIT: Okay, I think I completely do not understand where to place things likes observers and such into my application. I now have it so that my viewcontroller is the subscriber and now I am getting closer to the behavior to I want. If anyone has good guides on MVC and software design with MVC/iOS development, please do share. Book recommendations are welcome also.

Comment: KVO is rearely a good idea. I would suggest that you have your singleton post an NSNotification and have your WeatherFetch subscribe to that. It can then retrieve the value from the singleton

Comment: Also you haven't needed the `@synthesize` statements for a number of years

Comment: From reading dozens of resources, aren't they extremely similar?

Comment: KVO and NSNotification?  Somewhat similar. KVO give you more information about what changed and how while NSNotification is an arbitrary message; it could be sent because a property changed, the user logged in, the time of day, whatever you want.  More importantly NSNotification is less complex and less fragile.

Comment: Besides the Apple documentation, got any guides for it? I mainly choose KVO because the guide I was following used KVO and it promised to be automatic

Answer (score 0):

Can't tell what causing the KVO error as there is a lack of precision but just telling what we've done in a similar case

this is how we allocate our instance of LocationHelper :

```
- (id)init { self = [super init];

if (!self) {
    return self;
}

// Check if the service is available
if ([CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled])
{
    // Init the location manager
    self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    self.locationManager.delegate = self;
    self.locationManager.pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically = YES;
    self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = LOCATION_ACCURACY_IN_METER;
}

return self;}
```

and then I don't understand why you're not using :

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations
```

and then use manager.location to call setWeatherLocation or sendWeatherRequest from here.

If it is not what you expect, please give more detail about your crash

Comment: This was the guide I was following http://derpturkey.com/cllocationmanager-singleton/. The error for KVO was that the message was recieved but not handled

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest instead of creating a singleton just create an instance on app delegate and save the user coordinates on appdelegate that way you get user precise location at any time maybe you will need to tweak its accuracy so that it doesn't drain battery and appdelegate is already a singletion :)

If you want to do with singletion
The crash with KVO is because of this line:

```
[[LocationFetch sharedInstance] addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"currentLocation" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:nil];
```

When you add an observer you have to remove it yourself,try this in the singleton file:

```
- (void)dealloc {
 [[LocationFetch sharedInstance] removeObserver:self forKeyPath:@"currentLocation"];
}
```

I am not 100% sure on removing observer from a singleton class.The code looks weird to me but i think it will work